# react native display x number of rows from an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Supposing you have an array of 10 items in react native and you only want to display just 5 on a screen.

DATA

```
state = {
      people: [
       {firstName: Ben, lastName: Mark},
       {firstName: Linda, lastName: Hanson},
       {firstName: Arthur, lastName: Merlin},
       {firstName: Jesus, lastName: Joshua}
]
}
```

VIEW

```
<ScrollView >
      {
        people.map((item, i) => {
      return (
      <View key={i} style={styles.user}>
      <Card >
       <ListItem
        hideChevron={true}
        title={item.firstName} {item.lastName}
        />
        </Card>
      </View>
          );
        })
      }
    </ScrollView>
```

Please how can i achieve this?

Comment: That depends, do you want to show the first 5, the last 5, random 5 etc. Your question needs to be a bit clearer, what have you tried so far? The array you've given us only contains four. Your map code looks fine, so perhaps write another function which takes `this.state.people`, get's 5 people, then update the state with `this.setState({fivePeople: value});` and then map over that array instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, just use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on your array :

```
people.slice(0, 5).map((item, i)
```

It will only take the first 5 values of your array.

Answer (score 3):

You can `slice` your data

```
<ScrollView >
  {
    people.slice(0, 5).map((item, i) => {
  return (
  <View key={i} style={styles.user}>
  <Card >
   <ListItem
    hideChevron={true}
    title={item.firstName} {item.lastName}
    />
    </Card>
  </View>
      );
    })
  }
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: See @Treycos answer, try to edit/expand on that rather than making a duplicate answer.

Comment: sorry but it was not displayed when i had answered. its just 10 to 20 sec diff